# Can I Install Ubuntu first before installing Windows for dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Am i able to install ubuntu first and then install windows? I allocated ubuntu 15gb and im going to load the rest (900gb) for windows but will grub loader work? Or do i have to install windows first and then ubuntu? Thanks

Comment: Short answer: better install window first

Answer (score 5):

Though you can technically install Ubuntu and Windows in any order, I would highly recommend that you install Windows first.  This is because installing Windows on top of Ubuntu will likely result in messing up the [MBR](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Mbr).  When that happens, it can be very difficult to boot into Ubuntu, because the Grub dual-boot menu might disappear.  It can be a little tricky recovering from that, which you can read all about here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

So if you have the opportunity to start from scratch, installing Windows first and Ubuntu second could potentially make your life MUCH easier.

Answer (score 3):

I would most definitely install windows first, and the reason for that is:

1. This method is recommended by Ubuntu
2. It takes very little knowledge and all knowledge needed is easily available here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot
3. You dont have to think about how much space is required or save any partition space for linux. Simply install windows on all of your available space.
4. WHEN you start installing Ubuntu simply select "install along side windows", pull the handler to the amount of space you want Ubuntu to have available, and the installer will take care of all the partitioning (Which can be complicated for new users).
5. Finaly, IF you install windows AFTER you install linux. Windows will delete your boot record, meaning you would have to reinstall it. Thus making things more complicated then it has to be.

Usefull tips: If you have trouble booting into linux after installing. Have a look in your BIOS and look for safeboot and (and i stress and) se if this in anyway prohibits other operating systems (It will say so). If so disable it.

Good luck to you :)

PS: You might want a little more than 15GB... (You might like it :) :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Install Ubuntu.
2. Install Windows.
3. Update grub boot loader:

   1. Boot Ubuntu from a bootable media like USB/DVD.
   2. Open terminal by pressing `Alt+Ctrl+T`.
   3. Enter

      1. `sudo fdisk -l` (to find `X` and `Y`)*
      2. `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`
      3. `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdX`
   4. Boot Ubuntu from disk.
   5. Enter `sudo update-grub`.

* `X` is the drive letter and `Y` is the partition number on which your Ubuntu is installed (for example`sda1`).

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing for extra info.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not a Linux-based solution, you can (totally  GUI):

1. Install Ubuntu
2. Install Windows
3. Install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) in Windows and set the boot loader default boot in Ubuntu using Windows environment
4. (You could skip this and let BCD handle your system's boot, I wouldn't) Reboot in Ubuntu and install Grub in MBR, if not in command line use [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer).

ps:  I suppose you have set some swap space for the Linux install.

Comment: @ David Foerster: Is this the reason you clicked the "This answer is not useful"? This was a windows-linux question... I gave a tested solution!

Comment: You're correct. I didn't look closely enough at the nature of the question. I fixed some spelling mistakes in your answer so I can reverse the down vote. I cannot retract the flag though.

Comment: Fair enough. We sould look twice before accusing... "Better a free guilty than a wronged innocent".

Answer (score 0):

They can be installed in either order. The only difference is that installing Windows first will allow the Linux installer to detect it and add an entry for it in the bootloader automatically.