# How to dual boot Windows 10 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a desktop with Ubuntu 14.04 as the Operating System. How would I dual-boot Windows 10 onto my desktop? Thank you very much. I understand it would be much easier to do the other way around, but it would be greatly appreciated if someone could explain the process or provide a link that does. Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an answer here:

[Can I Install Ubuntu first before installing Windows for dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313623/install-linux-first-before-windows)

Check the link in the second (last) answer. In short, installing Windows on top of Linux, might make the GRUB2 menu disappear. The link gives instructions on how to restore it, in that case.