# Why won’t Windows 10 boot up in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 as my main operating system currently and I tried to switch from Windows10 to Ubuntu20.04, and it worked all good but now I want to Dual Boot Windows and Ubuntu. I made a new Partition in my Hard Disk and got everything ready But when I try to boot up my windows 10 USB Drive it never boots up and defaults to Ubuntu. In BIOS it says I already have Windows Boot Manager and Ubuntu Boot and I also have USB Flash Drive First, CD/ROM Second, and OS BOOT last my usb is all good and I think it has the correct formatting I also have tried to delete Ubuntu all together and just get Windows10. I deleted everything and wiped my hard disk but I still can’t get into Windows all I want is to Dual Boot Windows and Ubuntu or to just have windows back altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment. Here's a way that I've used many times:

- Install Windows first, see https://askubuntu.com/a/313631/976489
- During the installation, in the "Installation Type" page,  select "Something else".

I'm assuming you know how to allocate space for `/`, `/home` and `swap`. Just follow the top links in Search.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a desktop with SATA ssd, here's a weird solution. You can unplug your hard drive, boot from the usb, and while Windows is booting to install, replug the hard drive. All OS's should support this technique (Windows does) and it's a really good way to force your BIOS to boot from USB :). Now you can install Windows (on a different hard disk) and then do the same thing to boot from your ubuntu hard disk. Then run the `sudo update-grub` command in Ubuntu and you're good to go with a dual boot :)

Edit: it only works if you have a second physical hard disk for windows

Answer (score 0):

@Irsu85 reminded me of another issue you might be facing.
This happens for new laptops with an SSD. I was unable to dual-boot my newly purchased Lenovo Flex 15 2-in-1, which had an SSD.

Steps to fix:

- Go to `Setup Utility`(press F12 or F2 on startup) --> `Configuration` --> `SATA controller Mode`. Set it to `AHCI`.
- Dual-boot it as usual.

**Note**: Keep mode as `AHCI` permanently, don't switch it back after installation.

[image]

Took me around 2 days to figure it out. Intel RST(Optane), the default option, actually slows down a system with an SSD.

PS: I encountered another issue in 2022, see [fix](https://gist.github.com/sanjarcode/3dc47b0d69526435753a199dfd60dcfc#file-os-installation-md)